# Problem with parsing JSON result

Tags: objective-c, json

I have a problem with parsing a JSON result. This is what I get from my HTTP request:

```
{"subscriptions": [
     {"id":"A", "title":"A title"},  
     {"id":"B", "title":"B title"},  
]}
```

And this is what I'm doing in my code:

```
// Getting the result<br>
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

// Creating the JSON parser<br>
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];

// Parse result in an object<br>
NSDictionary *result = [parser objectWithString:str];
```

So far everything works fine. I have one key/value pair in my result object which I think is the subscriptions object. But the problem is now: How can I access the inner objects of it like the id and title?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. The `,` is a separator, not a terminator. (It seems like your parser is error correcting, but you should get the source data fixed anyway)

Comment: Hello David,

thank you for the fast response. I'm getting this JSON from Google, so I think this shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON parser will create nested NSArray and NSDictionary objects for you. To get to the array use:

```
NSArray *array = [result objectForKey:@"subscriptions"];
```

Then access the objects in the array like so:

```
NSDictionary *arrayObject = [array objectForIndex:0];
```

And finally, to get one of the inner objects do:

```
NSString *stringObject = [arrayObject objectForKey:@"id"];
```